# как подключить SLF4J поверх Log4j

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

Мне достался проект, который использует slf4j.
Пусть там есть исходник Foo.java в пакете com.A, в котором идет логирвоание через slf4j

Я подключаю бибилотеки slf4j, slf4j-to-log4j, log4j
Далее кладу конфиги log4j.properties рядом.
Теперь путь в папках выглядят так : /prj/src/main/java/com/A/Foo.java
/prj/src/main/java/log4j.properties

Теперь все это собираю в джарник и кладу на application server
Но гадские логи все равно не пишутся! Может я неверно натсроил логирование?

Comment: log4j.properties верно сконфигурирован?

Comment: @Chubatiy да, уверен на 100 процентов

Comment: проект на maven? Если да - то положите log4j.properties  в /src/main/resources/ Если же нет, то подскажите, после компиляции  log4j.properties у вас находится в /classes/? Вот ещё хорошая статья(может поможет Вам) http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example/